# Harm to exposing mac address?

Tags: networking, mac-address

Just a simple question, just as the title states. I just want to know if there's any harm that could come from other people knowing your MAC address?

Just about the only thing I can think of, is if that person happened to be trying to access the network you're on, and that network filters access by MAC addresses.

The reason I ask is because often times videos and screenshots on the internet blur them out, and I have a video on Youtube that exposes several MAC addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAC addreses identify (in theory) a NIC uniquely (worldwide)... so these provide among other things the ability to recognize a computer even when it is using dynamic IP address...

As it is a best practice to minimize any exposure of data my recommendation would be the other way around: Is it absolutely necessary to expose this piece of data in this specific case ?

From what you describe I don't see any benefit but potential harm... so: don't expose any MAC unlesse absolutely necessary.

Comment: Well... I had blurred nearly everything else out. It was a video demonstrating me "hacking" a Facebook chat. All I did was arp poison, and then sniff. Then I was able to see the conversation that was taking place on the computer right next to me. This was meant to be an example of what HTTPS helps to protect against. I had blurred nearly everything else out, such as Facebook profile id's, and even the username on my computer.

The video has been up for a while, until I finally noticed I forgot to blur the MAC addresses. I'm just not sure if it's worth the trouble to edit the video.

Comment: @andrewjackson if the NIC/computer is not in use anymore anywhere then don't bother it... otherwise I would blur too even though it was a long time ago...

Answer (score 1):

In the past, the mac address was used in the calculation of GUIDs. That actually has led to capturing the author of a virus that contained such a GUID. So yeah, for him it was harmful.

Answer (score 0):

Oviusly if you can easly hide it do it.
but in general there isn't any real harm, today with a simple command on linux you can change your MAC addr as it.seen ny the network, as anybody could be anybody.